# PulseUI on Ubuntu 22.04 needs Chromium Embedded Browser, which doesn't download

Tags: software-installation, vpn

I have installed pulseUI VPN on Ubuntu 22.04. After setting the vpn address, I receive a dialogue box that "Chromium Embedded Browser (CEF) is not installed on this machine. [...] Do you want to download and install Chromium Embedded Browser?"

[image]

I accept, and a progress dialogue box pops up that says 'Installing Chromium Embedded Browser'. However, this appears to hang and the progress bar never fills after several hours.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While creating the post I found the instructions for [manually installing CEF](https://help.ivanti.com/ps/help/en_US/PDC/9.1R12/ag/pdc-admin-guide/Chromium_Embedded_Framew.htm). I did (with root permissions):

```shellsession
/opt/pulsesecure/bin$ ./setup_cef.sh install
```

And verified with

```shellsession
/opt/pulsesecure/bin$ ./setup_cef.sh check_installed
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually needed to use reinstall to see the errors: `/opt/pulsesecure/bin$ ./setup_cef.sh reinstall`

Comment: @Oren thanks, this is what I needed. I had an older version of Embedded Chrome from an old installation and `reinstall` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Pulse Secure needs root priviges to install CEF but for whatever reason does not ask the user for a password and instead sits there doing nothing.

The previous answer provides a command which fixes the issue. However, for whatever reason they have put a `$` in there. I don't know enough Bash to know if that's needed. Either way it fails.

Anyway assuming pulse secure is installed under `/opt`. you can check with check with `ls /opt/pulsesecure`.

The command should be

```
sudo /opt/pulsesecure/bin/setup_cef.sh install
```

That worked for me at least and got me past the error.

For completeness you also have the options:

```
sudo /opt/pulsesecure/bin/setup_cef.sh reinstall

sudo /opt/pulsesecure/bin/setup_cef.sh uninstall
```

and

```
sudo /opt/pulsesecure/bin/setup_cef.sh check_installed
```

Comment: The `$` you mentioned is the command prompt of the Bash session. The author wanted to provide the command the way it would look _when executed from the directory the program resides in_, i.e. first `cd /opt/pulsesecure/bin`, then `./setup_cef.sh install`.